# Providing both HTTP and WebSocket on same Route (Play Framework 2.1)

Tags: http, websocket, request, playframework-2.1, routes

Im trying to provide both a HTTP-Answer and a WebSocket on the same HTTP-Route.

```
    GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
    GET     /                           controllers.Application.ws()
```

In an older Version of the Play Framework, it was possible to define a Route for "WS" and thus distinguish between HTTP and WS Request. Since im using 2.1, I need another possibility to get both HTTP and WS Requests working on the same Route.

Since WebSocket and Result arent in the same typehierarchy, I cant defer the mapping to the handler method. 
Is there any way to reroute the request based on if its HTTP or WS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved if you write your own router to do it - the above is not possible with Plays router because you're saying you want to router `/` to two different end points, the default Play router doesn't look at anything but the request method and URI.  So, if you override `Global.onRouteRequest` to look something like this:

```
override def onRouteRequest(req: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  if (req.method == "GET" && req.path == "/" &&
      req.headers.get("Upgrade").exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("websocket))) {
    Some(controllers.Application.ws())
  } else {
    super.onRouteRequest(req)
  }
}
```

Then, remove the WebSocket route from your routes file.

If you want to do this for Java, it will look something like this:

```
public Handler onRouteRequest(play.api.mvc.RequestHeader req) {
  if (req.method().equals("GET") && req.path().equals("/") &&
      req.headers().get("Upgrade").isDefined() &&
      req.headers().get("Upgrade").get().equalsIgnoreCase("websocket")) {
    return play.core.j.JavaWebSocket.ofJson(new scala.Function0<WebSocket<JsonNode>>() {
      public WebSocket<JsonNode> apply() {
        return controllers.Application.ws();
      }
    });
  } else {
    return super.onRouteRequest(req);
  }
}
```

Not sure if I've got the syntax/types 100% correct there, but hopefully you can work it out.  Also, note I've assumed JSON websockets here, if you're using strings or byte arrays, then use `JavaWebSocket.ofString/ofBytes`.  And finally, note that this is an internal API and could break at any time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - that helped a lot!
Now im very close to my (clean) solution, but with one question left:
Im in Java right now, and the "onRouterRequest(req)"-Method needs to return an instance of type "Handler". Since "Result" or "WebSocket" is not a Handler, how can be the (controllers.Applications.ws()) call converted to be an instance of handler?

Comment: Edited my response to include Java solution.

Comment: I edited to improve Java code and confirmed it is working out. I wish I had known about this hack earlier.